# c# asp.net how to get month and day on sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, repeater

All I want to do is to get the date on the SQL database for only the month and day and bind it into repeater:

FRONT:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_content" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="date">
<p><%# Eval("BLG_DATE") %> of <span><%#Eval("BLG_DATE") %></span>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</repeater>
```

BACK:

```
daString = "SELECT * FROM [BLG] INNER JOIN [ACC] ON [BLG].ACC_ID=[ACC].ACC_ID WHERE [BLG].ACC_ID='" + userID + "'";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(daString, conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);    
rep_content.DataSource = dt;
rep_content.DataBind();
```

BLG Table:

```
BLG_ID,ACC_ID,BLG_TITLE,BLG_DES,BLG_DATE,BLG_IMG
```

Output should be:

```
23 of JAN
```

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries. When SQL queries are built by string concatenation, you leave yourself vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I don't know how to use SQL parameter. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DatePart` to get day and month

```
 daString = "SELECT datepart (dd, BLG_DATE) as DDay,datepart (mm, BLG_DATE) as DMonth
  FROM [BLG] INNER JOIN [ACC] ON [BLG].ACC_ID=[ACC].ACC_ID 
    WHERE [BLG].ACC_ID='" + userID + "'";
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(daString, conn);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);    
 rep_content.DataSource = dt;
 rep_content.DataBind();


 <p><%# Eval("DDay") %> of <span><%#Eval("DMonth") %></span>
```

Comment: HOW CAN I USE IT IN <%# EVAL("BLG_DATE")%> ?
Can you give me example?

Comment: Thank You! it works but i have a problem in DMonth its show number not JAN

Comment: Try this Replace (mm, BLG_DATE) to CAST(datepart (mm, BLG_DATE) AS CHAR(3))

Comment: Thank you for the answers the CAST(datepart (mm, BLG_DATE) AS CHAR(3)) din't work I change it to CAST(datename (month, BLG_DATE) AS CHAR(3)).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_content" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="date">
<p><%# Eval("DDay") %> of <span><%#System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("DMonth")))%></span>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</repeater>
```